# Custom js loop in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Help with a wp custom loop, i have a js script with a variable

```
<script>
var prueba='chihuahua';
</script>
```

i need pass this var to my custom loop:

```
<?php
    $catname = "<script>document.write(prueba);</script>";
    echo $catname; // show the correct pass js variable to php variable
    $posts = get_posts('category_name='.$catname);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo "hola";
    }
?>
```

But not display the posts, thanks 4 help

Answer (score 0):

You should use a jQuery AJAX function with either $.get, $.ajax, $.load, etc. Here is an example.

JS:

```
    <script>
    $ = jQuery;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your_code.php",
      data: { prueba: "chihuahua" }
    }).done(function(){
      //do some code
    });
    <script>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
        $catname = $_POST['prueba'];
        echo $catname; // show the correct pass js variable to php variable
        $posts = get_posts('category_name='.$catname);
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            echo "hola";
        }
    ?>
```

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks! the final code is:

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.state').click(function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = this.id;
            $('.info-container').slideDown();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../folder/wp-content/themes/theme/content-infoContainer.php",
                data: { prueba: id },
                success:function(response){
                    if(response != null && typeof response != undefined){
                        $('#resultado').html(response);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#resultado').html('<p>ERROR</p>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php include_once '../../../wp-blog-header.php';
$catname = $_POST['prueba'];
$category = get_the_category($catname);
global $post;
$posts = get_posts('category_name='.$catname);?>
<div class="container"><div class="col-xs-12 relative">
<p class="close">X
    <script>
    $('.close').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.info-container').slideUp();
    });
    </script>
</p>
<?php 
foreach ($posts as $post) : 
    setup_postdata($post);?>
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="distribuidor text-center">
        <?php the_field('title'); ?>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <p>
          Contacto: <?php the_field('contacto'); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
          Telefono: <?php the_field('telefono'); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
          Mail: <?php the_field('mail'); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
          Ciudad: <?php the_field('ciudad'); ?>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-offset-4">
        <div class="row">
          <a href="<?php the_field('map_url'); ?>" class="pin" target="_blank">
            <img src="<?php PRINT IMAGES ?>/pin.png" alt="pin">
          </a>
          <p class="text-center">
            ver mapa
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="state-heading text-center">
            <?php echo $catname; ?>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
endforeach;?>
    </div></div>
```

Thanks @Brandon